# problems getting string Bounds in Java Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics

I want to draw a string. at first, I get the string bounds using getStringBounds: 
getStringBounds(String, FontRenderContext)

and then, I use DrawString to draw the string. I do not know what the returned vales of getStringBounds ("x" and "y") are. 
Can anybody please help me?

Thanks,
Shadi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for example, for one string it returns: X=0, Y=-11, width=20, length=17. What do x and y mean?

With most Graphics methods you specify the top/left location for the drawing. For example

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

However, when you draw text you specify the bottom/left location for the drawing. So in your case you would use:

```
g.drawString("string", 0, 11);
```

In general terms I guess you would use the absolute value of the Y value in the drawString() method.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was great. but when you say the y coordinate of bottom-left point is something, it should certainly have a relation with the text's height, shouldn't it? In other words, if we have only height and length of the text, we can draw it everywhere on the image (xbase+width, ybase+height). I believe only w and h would be enough. what is y? if length=17, how can y=11 be the y coordinate of bottom-left point? I really appreciate if you can guide me more.

Comment: I have often found the diagram and discussion in [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) illuminating.

Comment: C# MeasureString returns the TopLeft corner and width and height, whereas java's stringBounds returns the BottomLeft and width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getStringBounds%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.font.FontRenderContext%29).

> Returns the bounds of the specified String in the specified FontRenderContext. The bounds is used to layout the String.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>    str - the specified String
>    frc - the specified FontRenderContext
> Returns:
>    a Rectangle2D that is the bounding box of the specified String in the specified FontRenderContext.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I have already studied this short description in different tutorials. However, for example, for one string it returns: X=0, Y=-11, width=20, length=17. What do x and y mean? that is what I do not understand.

Comment: Re: x=0, y=-11 I have the same question. I believe they are x- and y-offsets from the start of the baseline; if the baseline is (100,200) the upper-left coordinates of the bounding rectangle will be x=100 + 0, y = 200 + -11 = 89. When I draw the bounding rectangle using these coordinates, the left, right and bottom of the rectangle are perfect, but the top seems to be too high. Still investigating. It would nice if I could find a complete discussion of this in the Java documentation.